# Combo move list for Zeno Clash

Tags: zeno-clash

There's a [guide for the sequel on Steam](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=143597216), not for the original game. I've forgot everything explained in tutorials and the game basically can't be completed by only using basic moves. Is there a similar guide for  [Zeno Clash](http://store.steampowered.com/app/22200) (2009)?

Comment: Why is this flagged as a recommendation request? The question is asking for a combo list. Answers can just provide a list rather than needing to link off-site.

Comment: There is a similar guide in [french](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=565784233), in case-someone wants to translate, or trusts google translate